# Null homotopic by simplicial approximation

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

If $m<n$ use the simplicial approximation theorem to prove that any map $f:S^m\to S^n$ is null homotopic. Deduce that $\pi_1(S^n)$ is trivial if $n>1$.

we have not covered lot on simplicial approximation. I don't have any reference book ether. If you know any book that has lot of information and solved problems about simplicial map and approximation then please give me the link.

And if you could do this for me then i would be blessed...

Comment: Did you try Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology"? It is free to download.

Comment: No, I didn't see it before, i will find now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One particular consequence of simplicial approximation of maps $f:S^m\to S^n$ with $m<n$ is that any such map is homotopic to one which is not surjective: indeed, a simplicial map maps simplex to simplices of no greater dimension, and it follows that any point in the interior of an $n$-dimensional simplex of the codomain is not in the image.

Now it is very easy to show that a non-surjective map $S^n\to S^m$ (whatever the dimensions) is homotopic to a constant map.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept that every map from a contractible space is trivial, notice that $S^n-\{x\}$ is iso. to $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. Then $f$ can be expressed/"factored" as a composition of maps, one map with domain $\mathbb R^n$. For $\pi_1$ use the same "factorization" of f and functoriality properties of $\pi_1$. EDIT Note we use simplicial approximation , as mentioned by Mariano, to allow for the fact that the map is ( homotopic to a map that is ) not onto.

Comment: You mixed up $m$ and $n$, which in this question is problematic. In any case, you cannot take a point out of the domain of functions and expect anything sensible with respect to homotopy. In this case, you have little else but to show that you can take a point out of the *codomain*, and that is what the simplicial approximation lemma allows you to do.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Sorry , just edited. The removed point is in the codomain. And I will edit the point about the use o simplicial approx.